# Javascript/canvas: draw polylines in real-time, what is the optimal data structure?

Tags: javascript, performance, data-structures, html, canvas

We're using Javascript to draw polylines on a `<canvas>` element, based on some spatial and time coordinates. Specifically, each point in the line has the following properties:

```
* point.x
* point.y
* point.time
```

meaning that at the time `point.time` we extend the polyline with an additional segment to `point.x/point.y`. Being time-based, it's essential that the data structure for  the set of all points be as efficient as possible in terms of access time.

Intuitively, I believe that a simple array with `3 x N` elements (for N nodes) will work best.

Do you have any other suggestions for a suitable structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have access to pointers or anything else, so you're basically left to arrays and objecta in JavaScript.

Since your problem is fairly easy, and requires only linear access, a `[x, y, t, x, y, t, x, y, t]` array should indeed be the fastest way to access the things.

However keep in mind that access to the data won't be the limiting factor here, `<canvas>` drawing performance, especially in Browser without Hardware Acceleration (which is currently still the majority), will be pretty bad if you draw on either a very big canvas, or many lines in a short amount of time.

Oh and last but not least, test it, don't make assumptions about performance, remember:
"Premature optimization is the root of all evil"

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer that point were an object of object, with time keys storing coordinates, like

```
   point = {
      <time1> : {
         x : ... ,
         y : ...
      },
      <time2> : {
         x : ... ,
         y : ...
      },
      ...

   }
```

so you can access directly with `point.time.x` and `point.time.y`, since x and y are related to a specific time (if I well understood)

instead, with a flat array given a specific time you should make offset operation to retrieve x and y, not so elegant